# Android javadoc does does not display

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc

I am having a problem with my android standard library javadoc, it does not show up when I hover over Objects in my code.

Example:

**android.app.Activity


Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc.**

I have tried changing the Java Build Path to point to 

C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/docs/reference

However, I hit validate and then ok and the location changes back to :
file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/docs/reference


Before- Images shows me changing the path
[image]

After- images shows eclipse reverting javadoc to the location back to the original location
[image]

I am trying to pick-up some android for a school project, and having that Javadoc would be awesome!

BTW:
1. i have tried following these steps: http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2011/02/losing-javadocs-in-eclipse-solution.html

2. I have the java doc installed in can open the file in my browser in the C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/docs/reference location

Thanks in advance to whoever solves this !

Answer (score 0):

you must download the `Documents` for the current Android API Version, you can download it from eclipse menu:
Window >> Android SDK and AVD Manager >> Available packages  ! then select the API Version match your need.

Comment: I already have all available packages installed and can open the API from my local C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/docs/reference location.

Comment: try to run eclipse as Administrator (right click then run as admin...)